# Insert process after On Duplicate Key Update

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Example i have temporary **table 1** `(Home_Temp)` with field `(home_id, home_name)` and contain data. I want to insert all data from **table 1** to **table 2** (Home_History). **Table 2** consist field `(home_id, home_name, status)`. The default value for 'status' is 1. The primary key for `Home_Temp` is `home_id` while Home_History is `home_id` and `status`.

For the first time insert process, data can be insert from **table 1** to **table 2** with default value for 'status' is 1. For second time insert process with same `home_id`, i want to insert the `home_name` and status to '1'. But the old data with same `home_id` and `home_name` i want to update to status '0'. Meaning the latest `home_id` have status value '1'. The old home_id have status value '0'. The code is successful until update the status for old `home_id` to '0'.

```
$stmt = $dbcon->prepare("INSERT INTO Home_History (home_id, home_name) SELECT home_id, home_name FROM Home_Temp ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE status = '0'");
$stmt->execute();
```

But how to insert the latest data? I try to do code below but it seems nonsense and not working.

```
$stmt = $dbcon->prepare("INSERT INTO Home_History (home_id, home_name) SELECT home_id, home_name FROM Home_Temp ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE status = '0' AND INSERT INTO Home_History (home_id, home_name) SELECT home_id, home_name FROM Home_Temp");
$stmt->execute();
```

How can i make sure the latest insert data has status '1' while the old data has status '0'?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want, after your insert, for home_id/home_name values added to Home_History to have status 1 and values that weren't able to be added to have status 0.  To do this you need a unique key on `(home_id, home_name)`, not `(home_id, status)`.

Answer (score 0):

For execute two query you cant use "AND" but use this code :

```
$sql = "
INSERT INTO Home_History (home_id, home_name) SELECT home_id, home_name FROM 
Home_Temp ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE status = '0'; 
INSERT INTO Home_History (home_id, home_name) SELECT home_id, home_name FROM 
Home_Temp; 
";

try {
     $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
     $stmt->execute();
    }
```